# Remove count badge on Vuetify data table header with multi-sort?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I am struggling to remove the badge count of how many columns are selected in multisort next to the column names 'Leído' and "Fecha de envío"...

[image: View]

The badge is span with class `v-data-table-header__sort-badge`.

[image: Class of badge]

And if I edit the html via Chrome and add 'display: none' it gets removed... However I am unable to override it via css in the code.

Is there any other way to remove the badge?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I've found the way by using !important modifier but I don't know if there is a better way to achieve that

```
.v-data-table-header__sort-badge {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: At least provide some link for regenerating issue

Comment: It is for the Data Table component of Vuetify (multisort case) https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/

Comment: just add `display: none` to the badge class. See the working pen here https://codepen.io/kiran589/pen/RwMQxbV?editors=0100

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that you've already found the same way. IMO the use of `v-deep` is recommended for modifying Vuetify core classes. Here is the reference I found for Scoped CSS in Vue: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: Thank you! For deleting arroy is there a header prop to that, but it seems for that badge isn't another option